# Объединение двух запросов в один

Tags: sql

Добрый вечер. У меня есть два запроса следующего вида:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS firtsRes
FROM tableName
```

и второй:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS secondRes
FROM tableName
WHERE fieldName > someValue
```

Мне нужно получить результат деления firstRes/secondRes. Можно ли получить его в одном запросе, иными словами, объяденить два вышеуказанных запроса в один? Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Andy_Reed

        select count(*)/sum(case when fieldName > someValue then 1 else 0 end) from tableName;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableName
WHERE fieldName > someValue)
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/`t2`.`secondRes` AS `itogo`
    FROM `table_1`
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS `secondRes` FROM `table_2` WHERE `fieldName` > `someValue`
) t2
```

P.S. Выше запрос я написал для двух таблиц, но и для одной - [так же работает](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3714e9/2/0)

Comment: Аккуратнее, пожалуйста. Какие table_1, table_2?

Comment: @alexlz, а в чем нужно быть аккуратней?

Comment: В задании имя таблицы tableName (одно). У Вас в FROM table_1 и table_2 (два). Или я неправильно понял ТС, или Вы.

Comment: @alexlz, вообще-то, не сложно заметить, что в дополнении, я указал, что для одной так же работает.

Comment: Приношу извинения.