# Объединить 2 запроса в 1

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Помогите объединить 2 запроса в один

```
SELECT id FROM players WHERE player = 'test'
SELECT * FROM history WHERE id = id
```

Comment: [Объединение запросов, смотрите вариант который вам нужен](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/193629/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD)

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае будет так:

```
SELECT h.* FROM `players` p JOIN `history` h ON (h.id=p.id) WHERE (p.player='test')
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` предполагает, что в history может не быть данных. Почему тогда в секции `SELECT` лишь  `h.*` ? Зачем выводить пустые строки в выборке при их наличии?

Comment: Спасибо! Поторопился. Исправил :)

Comment: Этот запрос подойдет, если допустим строку с id не найдет, он пропустит ее или выведет null?

Comment: Этот запрос, выполнится стандартно.

Comment: Если мой ответ решил ваш вопрос - отметьте его, как решение :)